# Undeclared struct usage

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

Using reqwest, I'm trying to convert the response into a structure. I'm following the example from this [site](https://docs.rs/serde_json/latest/serde_json/).

My file: twilio.rs, I have the following code

```
//use serde::{Serialize, Deserialize};
use serde_json::json;
use serde::Deserialize;
use serde::Serialize;

#[derive(Debug, Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct TwilioResponse {
    body: String,
    ...
}

pub mod twilio_service{

    pub struct Twilio {
        url: String,
        ...
    }



    impl Twilio {
        pub fn new(url: String, phone_number: String, account_sid: String, auth_token: String, message: String, send_to: String) -> Twilio {
            Twilio {
                url,
                phone_number,
                account_sid,
                auth_token,
                message,
                send_to
            }
        }

        pub async fn send(&self) {

            let url = format!("{}{}{}", self.url, self.account_sid, "/Messages.json");

            let client = reqwest::Client::new();
            let res = client.post(url)
                .basic_auth(&self.account_sid, Some(&self.auth_token))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .form(&[("From", &self.phone_number), ("To", &self.send_to), ("Body", &self.message)])
                .send()
                .await
                .unwrap();


            let text_response = res.text().await.unwrap();
            let json: twilio::TwilioResponse = serde_json::from_str(&text_response).unwrap();


        }
    }   
 }
```

The problem I have is when I compile the app, I get the following error:

```
let json: twilio::TwilioResponse = serde_json::from_str(&text_response).unwrap();
                   ^^^^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `twilio`
```

If I modify the code to:

```
let json: TwilioResponse = serde_json::from_str(&text_response).unwrap();
```

I then get the error

```
let json: TwilioResponse = serde_json::from_str(&text_response).unwrap();
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ not found in this scope
```

This is my first attempt in Rust and needing advise.  Thanks

Comment: Did you install the `twilio` crate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your first attempt is that a bare `twilio` in the use refers to either a crate or a *submodule* of the current module or some other imported symbol, neither of which exist.

Depending on where you declare the `twilio` module there are a couple of ways to import it.

1. Since `twilio_service` is a submodule of `twilio` you can use the `super` keyword, which means the module above this one:

   ```rust
   use super::TwilioResponse;
   ```
2. If `twilio` is directly declared in your `lib.rs` or `main.rs` you can use `crate` to refer to the crate root and specify the full path from there:

   ```rust
   use crate::possible_more_modules::twilio::TwilioResponse;
   ```

There is a third possibility, you actually meant to use a crate named `twilio` if so you have to add that to your `[dependencies]` in `Cargo.toml`:

```toml
[dependencies]
twilio = "*"
```